# Hide span with CSS but showing tooltip (has to work with high contrast and IE8)

Tags: html, css, tooltip, screen-readers, high-contrast

i want to hide a span element containing a tooltip using the same color for font as for the background, so that it is visible to screenreaders and invisible on the page but if you hover over it, you can still see the tooltip (which does not work with display:none).

but this does not work, if you turn on high contrast on windows, as the text is shown.

how can this be accomplished?
needs to work with IE 8 and without JS.

Thanks for your help!

```
<span title="vers_1.2.3.4" style="font-color:#000; background-color:#000">
Version
</span>
```

SOLUTION:

```
<span title="vers_1.2.3.4" style="font-color:#000; background-color:#000;">
 <p style="display:none">Version</p>
</span>
```

Comment: please fiddle your code

Comment: use visibility:hidden;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this fiddle, may be this is you want

http://jsfiddle.net/8s1rbp65/2/

```
<span title="vers_1.2.3.4" style="font-color:#FFF; background-color:#fff">
    <p>Version</p>
</span>

span p{
    color:transparent;
    border:1px solid #000;//this is to identify the text, remove this
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code. i modified it (cause color:transparent does not work) and it works (will add it in the description).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using plain `color:#000;` have you tried using `color:transparent;`. One of these should make your text invisible.

Comment: unforunately neither works (guess color=transparent isnt comp. with IE8)

Comment: color:rgba(0,0,0,0); maybe this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `visibility:hidden;` to hide to content, it will give the required space unlike `display:none;`

Comment: Don't think this is suitable in this case as the OP states that they want the content to be visible to screen readers. See [Screen reader visibility](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Screenreader_Visibility) for more info.

Comment: visibility:hidden also hides the tooltip :(